# R StepReg stepwise gives 'y' should be numeric or character vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a stepwise regression on a data frame using StepReg, like this:

```r
library(StepReg)

stepwise(BR_Click34_Crowd_pos[,c(10:45)], 
         y = BR_Click34_Crowd_pos[,c(10)], 
         exclude = BR_Click34_Crowd_pos[,c(15,17,23:25,31,32)], 
         selection = "bidirection", 
         select = 'adjRsq', 
         0.01, 
         0.05)
```

The data frame holds 45 columns of numeric data, with columns 10 - 45 passed in with column 10 as the output variable and columns 11 - 45 as the input variables, but with some columns excluded.  The error message is " 'y' should be numeric or character vector " which refers to column 10 and using as.numeric on column 10 gives a different error ('list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double') and as.vector on column 10 gives the error ('y' should be numeric or character vector).  Any thoughts, please?

Comment: we can't debug this without a reproducible example.  At the very least, can you edit your question to include the results of `str(BR_Click34_Crows_pos[10])` ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Can you please include a reproducible example, which will make it easier for others to help you.Consider looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Including your data, or a subset of it would be a great first step.

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker, I'd misunderstood the data format required.

Comment: Thank you @MarkNeal, I'd misunderstood the data format required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is produced because the function is expecting the name of the `y` variable in quotes or as a numeric column number not as a pointer to a column in the dataframe `BR_Click34_Crowd_pos[,c(10)]`

See the documentation for examples...

```r
stepwise(yx[,3:12], y = "Y1", exclude = "Y3", 
         selection = "bidirection", select='adjRsq', sle = 0.01, sls = 0.05)
```

Comment: Many thanks @ChuckP.  I'd read "Numeric or character vector ..." as wanting a vector of numeric data.  Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No problem your idea was perfectly logical just not what the function author meant.